# Java applet under Two-way SSL

Tags: java, ssl, applet

I have java applet in web application with Two-way SSL. Under IE11 and Java7u55 the applet pop ups **Identification required. Please select certificate to be used for authentication.** dialog box.

[image]

Is there any java plugin specification to explain that behavior? It Looks like the applet looses the ssl and try to recreate it again, doesn't it?

Java7u51 doesn't show this dialog box!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In applet's **archive** attribute I was setting the full path name to each JAR library (about 15).

The solution is to add **codebase** applet attribute to point the place where all JAR libraries reside.